# Как отправить форму несколько раз?

Tags: javascript

Как отправить форму несколько раз с разными данными?
Есть форма:

```
<form id="form" action="send.php" method="post">
    <input id="name" name="name">
    <input id="phone" name="phone">
</form>
```

Есть массив, который содержит в себе разные **name** и **phone**.
Как сделать так, чтобы пока не закончились данные в массиве, на каждой итерации цикла, отправлялась форма с новыми данными?

```
form = document.getElementById('form')
for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById('name').value=newArr[i].name
   document.getElementById('phone').value=newArr[i].phone
   form.submit()
}
```

Comment: никак, в данном случае

Comment: В таком варианте у вас форма сама уйдет на сервер и страница перегрузится. При первом вызове.

Comment: @AzizUmarov А в каком случае можно такое реализовать?

Comment: Останавливаете сабмит и в цикле через ajax fetch XMLHttpRequest отправляете данные

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form" action="send.php" method="post" target="myframe">
    <input id="name" name="name">
    <input id="phone" name="phone">
</form>
<iframe name="myframe" src="about:blank" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```